# Cant find the file i created on android tablet

Tags: android, file

/data directory in android is empty. I have installed a few applications and i also wrote code to create a file in /data/Myapp directory ,

I have these lines in OnCreate method , but i dont see any files in /data directory after running the program.

```
    File fileDir = getFilesDir();
    String filedir=fileDir.toString();
    Log.v("TEST","FILEDIR--->"+filedir);

       //output i got is FILEDIR--->/data/data/com.android.Test/files

    String strNewFileName = "test1.txt";
    String strFileContents = " MY FIRST FILE CREATION PRGM";

    File newFile = new File(fileDir, strNewFileName);
    try{

            boolean filestat = newFile.createNewFile();
            Log.v("TEST"," CREATE FILE =>"+ filestat);

                //output is CREATE FILE =>true indicating success

            FileOutputStream fo =
            new FileOutputStream(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
            fo.write(strFileContents.getBytes());
            fo.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) 
    {Log.v("TEST","Exception on create ");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On real device, you can't see these folders if it's not rooted. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446912/android-data-data-folder-empty) question.

If you want to write files in your app directory, then your code is OK. You can check that it is there in the same way you created it - from your application:

```
File myFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/test1.txt");
if (myFile.exists())
{
  //Good!
}
```

Comment: How can my application gain root access ? I tried viewing through "andexplorer" but it shows as empty. http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/

Comment: Application cannot get root access normally. see updated answer.

Comment: createNewFile() function returns true ,which means that the file is getting created without any problem. But rooting applies for even tablet pcs ? Say i'm developing application for getting input and storing the processed input  in "/data/com.android.mypackage/files" . Say the user is interested in viewing the file i created .Then the users cant use my application without rooting ?

Comment: Why won't you store it in SD card?

Comment: See here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal if you don't have SD card, you should have such storage inside the device.

Comment: yeah my device has a MicroSD slot , but i dont hav a microSD card with me.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I think you need to get SD card.

Comment: I would like to work with internal storage , as the file i'm going to store will be only a few Kilobytes.