# creating and writing to a file on internal storage

Tags: android, file, tablet

I would like to create a file in android tablet and write some data to it. (only a few kilobytes).

The link below has the code i tried, but i dont see the file that got created in /data directory. some one said i have to root my device for seeing those files.

**Question: I want to create and write to a file using the internal storage without rooting the device . Is it possible ?**

I'm posting this question as i couldn't find answers for

[Cant find the file i created on android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458327/cant-find-the-file-i-created-on-android-tablet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to create a file:

```
FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//write to the file stream
f.close();
```

That would normally create a file within internal storage that would be only accessible by your app.

Comment: I want to create a file using my app. But i should be able to view it after closing the app also. Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "view it", but you can use Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE and Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE modes instead of MODE_PRIVATE to make the file accessible by other apps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion !! I will try that .                                      Say i process some data and write the final output to a file "output.txt" . The user of my application should be able to see my final output file. As he might transfer it to his PC for further usage.

Comment: @m2n07 but how the user is gonna to see the file? Using a file manager app? Then Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE should be enough.

Comment: yes, The user will be using a file manager app (or) they will mount the device , so that they can transfer the file to PC. I just tried MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE , but in my "AndExplorer" i'm not able to see any file under /data directory.

Comment: I just installed a new "Android File Manager" app , it says that i don't have permission to access the /data folder .  I think i will better create a new folder for my app and create files inside it.

Comment: This will create the file under data/package_name/files. You can view the file from DDMS, but I don't think user will be able to see it.

Comment: You are correct !! But i'm also facing another problem where in the DDMS -> FileExplorer is always blank,but on the left side i'm able to see the device and logcat gets updated fine. probably i have to post as another question.

Comment: The method openFileOutput returns a fileOutputStream, not a file.